# Get the <th> element in a simple table while clicking <td> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my issue.

I have a simple table like this (for the example) :

```js
$('#tab tbody tr td').on('click', function() {
  var val = $(this).parent().find('table tbody tr th').text();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 3
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 4
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I am trying to `console.log(..)` the name of the column while i am clicking a `<td>` element.

I think it may be a simple solution but i can't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:eq()` & `index()` to achieve this.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#tab tbody tr td').on('click', function() {
  var val = $(this).index(); //get index no of td
  console.log($("thead th:eq(" + val + ")").text().trim()); //get th value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Test 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 2
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 3
      </th>
      <th>
        Test 4
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh yes sure, didn't think about the var index. I'm beginning in this, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad i was able to help :)